# How do I update $_SESSION variable when the mysqli table is updated?

Tags: php, session

I'm new to web programming and I have an issue with the way user $_SESSION variables are being handled. When a user logs into my website, I start a session like so -

```html
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['class'] = $row['class'];
$_SESSION['user_level'] = $row['user_level'];
$_SESSION['level'] = $row['level'];
$_SESSION['exp'] = $row['exp'];
$_SESSION['health'] = $row['health'];
```

Currently, if I want to update one of these session variables -

```
$_SESSION['strength'] += 10;
$db->query("UPDATE player SET strength=strength+10 WHERE id={$_SESSION['id']}");
```

I am doing it this way, because after I query the database, my session variables are not updating as well. If I unset the session variable, it logs the user out of the website. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: My issue was my understanding of how sessions worked, session variables are temporary and shouldn't be used for values that update inside the database. I should instead grab the variables directly from the database so that they update in real-time.

Comment: Where did you set $_SESSION['strength'] initially?

Comment: yeah. was wondering why he simply use $_SESSION['strength'] += 10; while not assign the session strength first. I bet the query also having problem. strength=strength+10 <= this should be an error. declare this first if u havent $_SESSION['strength'] = 10; then only you can use $_SESSION['strength'] += 10;

Comment: @NMAA actually you can use strength=strength+10 (assuming `strength` is an Integer column) in an update query

Comment: @AmirMB never knew that we able to use the data in the column. usually i use the value i have or query from db before doing db operation.

Comment: $_SESSION['strength'] is set when the user logs in, and is retrieved as an int through mysql. It's probably wrong for me to do it this way, but I'm still learning..

Comment: @NMAA to be fair, you even can use `$_SESSION['strength'] += 10;` without initiating it since php convert `null` to zero in + operation with an Integer

Comment: @CalebKious I didn't get what is not working in your code, could you please explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Amir for example, if I have a cron job that updates the database every hour, and sets the users health=maxhealth, I want it to also update with the users session. At the moment, it updates in the database, but on the website it still keeps the old values. Currently the only way for the values to refresh, is if the user logs out and logs back into the website.

Comment: @CalebKious It's not possible for a cron job to update a session variable since sessions are determined by the cookies which are sent by each user, it's probably better to store that value in DB and retrieve it whenever user requires it

Comment: @Amir Basically, how do I keep the $_SESSION['strength'] always equal to the $row['strength'] from the database? Am I using session wrong?

Comment: @CalebKious not possible since $_SESSION variable is a temporary variable

Comment: Is error reporting enabled and set to display? Is the session started in all pages using them and do all session arrays contain their respected value?

Comment: @Amir Thank you Amir! I'm cleaning up a lot of code now but I think I understand what my issue was. I was misunderstanding how sessions worked, I thought that they were unique for each user logged in and would be updated when tables updated. Now I'm just going to use sessions for variables that won't be updated.

Answer (score -2):

instead of "strength=strength+10" use in your query string
 "strength={$_SESSION['strength']}"

Comment: Why? And also OP's problem is the session variable, not the query

Comment: That works, but it still requires me to update the session variable manually. I want the session variable to update when the table updates.